# C# Save List<String> or Array in Settings.settings?

Tags: c#, settings

I would like to save User Settings in the Settings.settings.
I want to create new Settings/Rows on runtime, but I heard, that this isn't possible, so 
I thought, I could save the things in a List of Strings in the SettingsFile, but which Type do I must take?

`System.Collections.Generic.List<String>` is not known and
`System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` isn't working (Visual Studio throws Exception when choosing this o.O)

What can I do?