# How to add listbox items to settings?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

How to add all items from listbox to settings? I tried by arraylist but I had error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have no idea how to do this.
Settings:

> Name - listboxItems, Type - System.Collections.ArrayList,
>   Scope - Application

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Save listBox Items
            foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.listboxItems.Add(item);
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the `listboxItems` entry in the Settings is null.  Try:

```
var newList = new ArrayList();
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
{
    newList.Add(item);
}

Properties.Settings.Default.listboxItems = newList
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you want something typed in your settings (i.e. `string[]`, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885898/c-sharp-save-liststring-or-array-in-settings-settings).